# Transformation for isothermal coordinates of energy of harmonic maps between Riemann surfaces

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I am currently reading section "3.6 Maps Between Surfaces. The Energy Integral. Definition and Simple Properties of Harmonic Maps" in "Compact Riemann surfaces" by Jürgen Jost and he defines the energy of a map as follows

> Let $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$ be Riemann surfaces; suppose $\Sigma_2$ carries a metric, given in local coordinates by
> $$
> \rho^2(u)du d\overline{u}.
> $$
> Let $z = x + iy$ be a local conformal parameter on $\Sigma_1$.
> Now let
> $$
> u: \Sigma_1 \to \Sigma_2
> $$
> be a map, of class $C^1$ to start with. We define the energy integral of $u$ as
> $$
> \begin{align}
> E(u) &:= \int_{\Sigma_1} \rho^2(u) (u_z \overline{u}_{\overline{z}} + \overline{u}_z u_{\overline{z}}) \frac{i}{2} dz d\overline{z} \\
> &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\Sigma_1} \rho^2(u(z))(u_x \overline{u}_x + u_y \overline{u}_y)dxdy
> \end{align}
> $$
> ($u_z := \frac{1}{2} (u_x − iu_y), u_{\overline{z}} := \frac{1}{2} (u_x + iu_y)$, etc., subscripts denoting partial
> derivatives.)

What I don't understand basically boils down to one question:

- By plugging in $u_z := \frac{1}{2} (u_x − iu_y), u_{\overline{z}} := \frac{1}{2} (u_x + iu_y)$, etc., in the first line of the definition of the energy integral I managed to get the $(u_x \overline{u}_x + u_y \overline{u}_y)$ part of the second line but I don't understand how the differentials transform and how they seem to "suck up" the imaginary $i$.

Comment: For starters, $\frac i2 dz\wedge d\bar z. = dx\wedge dy$.

Comment: Argh, of course it is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the little nudge from [Ted Shifrin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/71348/ted-shifrin) in the comments I can answer my own question:

> By plugging in $u_z := \frac{1}{2} (u_x − iu_y), u_{\overline{z}} := \frac{1}{2} (u_x + iu_y)$, etc., in the first line of the definition of the energy integral I managed to get the $(u_x \overline{u}_x + u_y \overline{u}_y)$ part of the second line but I don't understand how the differentials transform and how they seem to "suck up" the imaginary $i$.

We plug in $u_z := \frac{1}{2} (u_x − iu_y), u_{\overline{z}} := \frac{1}{2} (u_x + iu_y)$, etc., and $z = x + iy$ to get
$$
\begin{align}
E(u) :&= \int_{\Sigma_1} \rho^2(u)(u_z\overline{u}_\overline{z} + \overline{u}_z u_\overline{z})\frac{i}{2}dzd\overline{z} \\
&= \int_{\Sigma_1} \rho^2(u)(u_z\overline{u}_\overline{z} + \overline{u}_z u_\overline{z})\frac{i}{2}dz \wedge d\overline{z} \\
&= \int_{\Sigma_1} \rho^2(u(z))\left(\frac{1}{2}(u_x -iu_y)\frac{1}{2}(\overline{u}_x + i\overline{u}_y) + \frac{1}{2}(\overline{u}_x - i\overline{u}_y)\frac{1}{2}(u_x + iu_y)\right)\frac{i}{2}d(x+iy) \wedge d(x - iy) \\
&= \int_{\Sigma_1} \rho^2(u(z))\left(\frac{1}{4}(u_x\overline{u}_x + iu_x\overline{u}_y -i\overline{u}_xu_y + u_y\overline{u}_y ) + \frac{1}{4}(u_x\overline{u}_x + i\overline{u}_xu_y - iu_x\overline{u}_y + u_y\overline{u}_y )\right)\frac{i}{2}d(x+iy) \wedge d(x - iy) \\
&= \int_{\Sigma_1} \rho^2(u(z))\frac{1}{2}(u_x\overline{u}_x +  u_y\overline{u}_y)\frac{i}{2}d(x+iy) \wedge d(x - iy) \\
&= \int_{\Sigma_1} \rho^2(u(z))\frac{1}{2}(u_x\overline{u}_x +  u_y\overline{u}_y)\left(\frac{i}{2}(dx+idy \wedge dx - idy)\right) \\
&= \int_{\Sigma_1} \rho^2(u(z))\frac{1}{2}(u_x\overline{u}_x +  u_y\overline{u}_y)\left(\frac{i}{2}(dx\wedge dx -idx \wedge dy +idy\wedge dx + dy \wedge dy)\right) \\
&= \int_{\Sigma_1} \rho^2(u(z))\frac{1}{2}(u_x\overline{u}_x +  u_y\overline{u}_y)\left(\frac{i}{2}(0 - idx \wedge dy - idx\wedge dy + 0)\right) \\
&= \int_{\Sigma_1} \rho^2(u(z))\frac{1}{2}(u_x\overline{u}_x +  u_y\overline{u}_y)dx\wedge dy \\
&= \int_{\Sigma_1} \rho^2(u(z))\frac{1}{2}(u_x\overline{u}_x +  u_y\overline{u}_y)dxdy
\end{align}
$$

which is exactly the second line.