# Definition of the energy functional for harmonic maps between compact Riemann surfaces

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I am currently reading "[Restrictions on harmonic maps of surfaces](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938376900422/pdf?md5=79a360fbd50aeae467c673f9289959b9&pid=1-s2.0-0040938376900422-main.pdf)" by J. Eells and J. C. Wood and don't understand how they get to the definition of the energy functional. The first paragraph of the paper states:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be closed orientable smooth surfaces, and $\phi: X \to Y$ a smooth map. Relative to Riemannian metrics $g,h$ on $X,Y$ we say that $\phi$ is harmonic if the divergence of its differential vanishes identically. In isothermal charts, writing $h = \sigma^2(w)dwd\overline{w}$ and representing $\phi$ in the form $z \to w(z)$, that condition is expressed by
> $$
> w_{z\overline{z}} + (2\sigma_w/\sigma)w_z w_\overline{z} = 0,
> $$
> being the Euler-Lagrange equation associated to the energy functional
> $$
> E(\phi) = \frac{1}{2}\int \vert d\phi(x) \vert^2 dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_X \sigma^2(w(z))\left[ \vert w_z \vert^2+ \vert w_\overline{z}\vert^2 \right] dx dy.
> $$

where subscripts denote partial derivatives and $w_z := \frac{1}{2}(w_x - iw_y), w_\overline{z} := \frac{1}{2}(w_x + iw_y)$, etc.

What I don't understand is this:

- The general definition of the energy integral for harmonic maps is $E(\phi) = \frac{1}{2}\int \vert d\phi \vert^2 d\mu_g = \frac{1}{2}\int_M g^{ij}\frac{\partial \phi^\alpha}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial \phi^\beta}{\partial x^j}h_{\alpha\beta}d\mu_g$ where $\mu_g$ represents the standard measure induced in $M$ from the Riemannian metric $g$. I tried plugging in the metrics in their isothermal representation but I don't seem to be able to get anywhere. How do they arrive at the last equation in the definition of the energy functional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard calculation, but a bit hard to pin down in the literature. Maybe see p. 8 of Schoen and Yau's "Lectures on Harmonic Maps".

Here is my rewriting of it. Note I got the answer off by 2 from Eells and Wood.

As you naturally wanted, I will work everything in the real version. So let
$$
w=u+iv,\ z=x+iy,
$$
and the isothermal metrics on target and domain are
\begin{gather*}
\sigma^2(u, v)(du^2+dv^2)=\sigma^2(w)dwd\bar w,\\
\tau^2(x, y)(dx^2 + dy^2) = \tau^2(z)dzd\bar z.
\end{gather*}
(Since the energy is conformal invariant in dimension 2, the $\tau$ would not matter at the end, but for concreteness, we introduce it.)

Then a direct calculation (for just complex numbers) gives
$$
|w_z|^2 + |w_{\bar z}|^2 = \frac{1}{2}(u_x^2 + u_y^2 + v_x^2 + v_y^2).
$$

Then applying your general formula in this case,
\begin{align*}
|d\phi|^2 &= h_{\alpha\beta}\frac{\partial \phi^\alpha}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial \phi^\beta}{\partial x^j}g^{ij}\\
&=\sigma^2 (u_x^2 + u_y^2 + v_x^2 + v_y^2) \tau^{-2}\\
&=2\sigma^2 (|w_z|^2 + |w_{\bar z}|^2) \tau^{-2}.
\end{align*}
Now
$$
d\mu_g = \sqrt{\det g}\,dxdy = \tau^2 dxdy.
$$

Therefore, the energy of the map is
\begin{align*}
E(\phi) &= \frac{1}{2}\int 2\sigma^2( |w_z|^2 + |w_{\bar z}|^2) \,dxdy\\
&=\int_X \sigma^2(w(z))( |w_z|^2 + |w_{\bar z}|^2) \,dxdy.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and not only for pointing out a reference but also for showing explicitly why the $\tau$ does not matter at the end!

Comment: Another quick question: how do you arrive at $\frac{\partial \phi^\alpha}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial \phi^\beta}{\partial x^j} = (u^2_x + u^2_y + v^2_x + v^2_y)$?

Comment: Right, so concretely the metrics in matrix form are $(h_{\alpha\beta})=\begin{pmatrix} \sigma^2 & 0\\ 0&\sigma^2\end{pmatrix}$ and $(g_{ij})=\begin{pmatrix}\tau^2 & 0 \\ 0 & \tau^2\end{pmatrix}$. When computing $h_{\alpha\beta}\frac{\partial \phi^\alpha}{\partial x^i}\frac{\partial \phi^\beta}{\partial x^j}g^{ij}$, we must have $\alpha=\beta$ and $i=j$ by the diagonal shape. Therefore there are 4 terms, and the final answer is $\sigma^2(u_x^2 + u_y^2 + v_x^2 + v_y^2)\tau^{-2}$. (So the whole expression a priori should have 16 terms, but now only 4, by the diagonal shapes of the metrics.)

Comment: Once again, thank you for the clarification. I totally forgot about the diagonal form of the metrics so this makes total sense!

Comment: Just another quick comment: I think your answer is actually correct and it was a typo in the paper above because [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4835726/transformation-for-isothermal-coordinates-of-energy-of-harmonic-maps-between-rie) I showed that $\frac{i}{2} dz \wedge d\overline{z} = dx \wedge dy$ and in "A Report on Harmonic Maps" by Eells and Lemaire they define the energy integral as $E(\phi) = \frac{i}{2}\int_M \sigma^2(w)\{\vert w_z \vert^2 + \vert w_{\overline{z}} \vert^2\} dz d\overline{z}$ which is exactly what we get with your answer.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I am happy when constants match :)